# implementing a stopwatch on a js game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a memory card game.
I want to show the time from the moment the user pressed on the first card till they win.
i dont understand how to make the stopwatch to continue counting while the player plays without it getting stuck or not refreshing the display enough.

HTML:

```
<h4 class="stopwatch">00:00:00</h4>
```

JavaScript:

```
while (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT !== flippedCouplesCount) {
    sec++;
    if (sec == 60) {
        min = min + 1;
        sec = 0;
    }
    if (min == 60) {
        hr = hr + 1;
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
    }
    elStopwatch.innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
```

Comment: hello. lacking a bit of javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}


<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```